# Sed bash replace containing a path pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I'm attempting to replace a string on bash script with the following

```
 sed -i -e \"s/__BUILD_NUMBER__/${version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}/g\" -e \"s/__BUILD_TIMESTAMP__/${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}/g\" package.json
```

But I'm getting the following error

sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'

these are the values of the variables

version= ase/bab/BAB

BUILD_NUMBER= 2.11.0.7

BUILD_TIMESTAMP= 2024-03-27_14-37-04

Comment: Use `jq` instead of `sed`

Comment: Your recent edits reveal that the commands were run in a Jenkinsfile inside double quotes, and apparently that's why you had backslashed the double quotes. Now that context is gone, and what you have is a trivial syntax error which however does not produce the symptom you are asking about. I'm tempted to vote to close as typo / unreproducible. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

use `#` as a delimiter

```
sed -i -e "s#__BUILD_NUMBER__#${version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}#g" -e "s#__BUILD_TIMESTAMP__#${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}#g" package.json
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess your command should be corret.You need to escape the sashes in your variabl with backslash:

```
version=ase\/bab\/BAB
```